# Check engine lights came on

Tags: warning-light

When i turned on my car 3 lights come on. My engine, battery and oil pressure. But when i start my ignition all 3 turn off and my car seems to be driving fine. Should i still have it looked at? I Checked my oils and everything seems fine. Thats the only thing I know how to check.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you turn the car off, then turn the key back to "On" without starting it, do the lights reappear?

Comment: Yes they do reappear. But never come on when the car starts. O yea i dont know if it matters but i have a 2010 honda civic XL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those warning lights are lit because the ignition is on and the engine is not running, therefore the alternator is not generating electricity and the oil pump is not creating oil pressure.

If the engine stalled you would expect the same lights to light up.  If any of the lights illuminate while the engine is running, then you should not ignore them.

What you are seeing is normal.

Answer (score 1):

Lights coming on when you turn on the ignition, so you can see they are working properly. Once the car is started all lights should go off, if any light stay on ot means you have some problem. Example if oil light stays on, it might mean you don't have enough oil or that you have some oil pump problem.

Comment: Ok so nothing is wrong right? I know they all flash when the car first turn on the car. But those 3 stay on until the car starts

Comment: Yes your car seems fine by info you gave us.

Comment: Ok thank you so much. Guess im a bit of a worrier really appreciate it. Hope you have a great day